# postfix and dovecot use /root/Maildir instead of /var/spool/mail

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a mailserver for testing with dovecot and postfix
this is the postfix config

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = postfix1.test.lan
mydomain = test.lan
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 10.10.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = posta.test.lan
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/

mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/mycert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/private/mykey.key
smtpd_tls_ciphers= high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, DES, 3DES, MD5, DES+MD5, RC4
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf
virtual_transport=dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
```

On dovecot I have only change this line

```
mail_home = maildir:/var/spool/mail/%u
```

I have also tried

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/spool/mail/%u
```

When I try to send an email instead of use /var/spool/mail
it try to use (and fail) the /root/Maildir!
Where is my conf wrong?Why don't use the /var/spool/mail as I configure?
I have tried without selinux but same thing..
Distro is latest centos 7

Comment: On the most basic level, you may need an alias to send roots mail to another account. Some of the logs may help though. I don’t think you’re actually using dovecote for local deliveries are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,dovecot were misconfigured.
And removing this line make server works fine

```
mynetworks = 10.10.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
```